# Incorrect page content loading for different countries in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, caching, cdn

I have the following issue and I can't find a solution right now.

I have a Wordpress site which works great but when someone tries to access the website from different country(for example Germany) the server loads completely different content under the same domain(it loads some store products).

Any ideas would be great right now!

Tried disabling plugins
Tried editing .htaccess file
Purged the cache of Wordpress site with plugin

This is the content of .htaccess file.

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /

# Bypass CDN for German and UK visitors
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(DE|de|UK|uk)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Which plugins did you use, did you tried to disable all plugins, did you tried to change theme, what you have in .htaccess, what you edited in .htaccess?

Comment: The plugin I used is LiteSpeed Cache, tried to deactivate almost all plugins, in .htaccess file I tried to add Bypass CDN for certain countries. The current state of the .htaccess file is default one

Comment: Did you solve the problem if you deactivate all plugins? Which CDN you use, is your cache from plugin of from CDN. You can update question with `.htaccess` code

Comment: I am not very familiar with CDNs but, the website is hosted on GCP. Deactivating the plugins didn't help.

Comment: Is it possible to have some redirects ?